# In my "Gears" program, why does the black circle (forest) keep spazzing?

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
// I am a very noobish programmer
public class Gears extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
    static boolean shoot;
    static int water = 500;
    static JLabel waterLabel = new JLabel("water: " + water + "G");
    static int fx2;
    static int fy2;
    public static int fuel = 999;
    static Random r = new Random();
    static BorderLayout bor = new BorderLayout();
    JButton craft = new JButton("Craft");
    static int balance = 0;
    static JLabel balanceLabel = new JLabel("$: " + balance);
    public Gears()
    {
        super("Gears");
        add(waterLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        setLayout(bor);
        setSize(1000,1000);
        add(balanceLabel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.getContentPane().add(new BasicCity(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Gears g = new Gears();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'q')
        {
            shoot = true;
            repaint();
        }

        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'w')
        {
            BasicCity.y = BasicCity.y - 5;
            BasicCity.ny = BasicCity.ny - 5;
            repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'a')
        {
            BasicCity.x = BasicCity.x - 5;
            BasicCity.nx = BasicCity.nx - 5;
            repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'd')
        {
            BasicCity.x = BasicCity.x + 5;
            BasicCity.nx = BasicCity.nx + 5;
            repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 's')
        {
            BasicCity.y = BasicCity.y +  5;
            BasicCity.ny = BasicCity.ny +  5;
            repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'W')
        {
            BasicCity.y = BasicCity.y - 5;
            BasicCity.ny = BasicCity.ny - 5;
            repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'A')
        {
            BasicCity.x = BasicCity.x - 5;
            BasicCity.nx = BasicCity.nx - 5;
            repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'D')
        {
            if(fuel != 0 == true && fuel > 0 == true)
            {
            BasicCity.x = BasicCity.x + 5;
            BasicCity.nx = BasicCity.nx + 5;
            repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'S')
        {
            if(fuel != 0 == true && fuel > 0 == true)
            {
            BasicCity.y = BasicCity.y +  5;
            BasicCity.ny = BasicCity.ny +  5;
            repaint();
            }
        }
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // 

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

class BasicCity extends JComponent{
    public static int x = 200;
    public static int y = 200;
    public static int nx = 217;
    public static int ny = 310;
    static int fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
    static int fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.fillOval(fx,fy,100,100);
    if(fx + 2 < x)
    {
        if(fy + 2 > y)
        {
            Gears.fuel = Gears.fuel + 100;
            fx = Gears.r.nextInt(200) + 1;
            fy = Gears.r.nextInt(200) + 1;
            if(fx + 10 < x == true || fx - 10 < x == true)
            {
                fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                if(fx + 10 < x == true || fx - 10 < x == true)
                {
                    fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                    fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                    if(fx + 10 < x == true || fx - 10 < x == true)
                    {
                        fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                        fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            g.fillOval(fx, fy, 100,100);
            Gears.balance = Gears.balance + 100;
            Gears.balanceLabel.setText("$: " + Gears.balance);
            repaint();
        }
    }
    if(fx - 2 < x)
    {
        if(fy - 2 > y)
        {
            Gears.fuel = Gears.fuel + 100;
            fx = Gears.r.nextInt(200) + 1;
            fy = Gears.r.nextInt(200) + 1;
            if(fx + 10 < x == true || fx - 10 < x == true)
            {
                fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                if(fx + 10 < x == true || fx - 10 < x == true)
                {
                    fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                    fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                    if(fx + 10 < x == true || fx - 10 < x == true)
                    {
                        fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                        fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            g.fillOval(fx, fy, 100,100);
            Gears.balance = Gears.balance + 100;
            Gears.balanceLabel.setText("$: " + Gears.balance);
            repaint();

        }

    }
    if(fx - 2 < x)
    {
        if(fy - 2  > y)
        {
            Gears.fuel = Gears.fuel + 100;
            fx = Gears.r.nextInt(200) + 1;
            fy = Gears.r.nextInt(200) + 1;
            if(fx + 10 < x == true || fx - 10 < x == true)
            {
                fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                if(fx + 10 < x == true || fx - 10 < x == true)
                {
                    fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                    fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                    if(fx + 10 < x == true || fx - 10 < x == true)
                    {
                        fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                        fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            g.fillOval(fx, fy, 100,100);
            repaint();

        }

    }
    if(fx + 2 < x)
    {
        if(fy +  2 > y)
        {
            Gears.fuel = Gears.fuel + 100;
            fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
            fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
            if(fx + 10 < x == true || fx - 10 < x == true)
            {
                fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                if(fx + 10 < x == true || fx - 10 < x == true)
                {
                    fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                    fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                    if(fx + 10 < x == true || fx - 10 < x == true)
                    {
                        fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                        fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            fx = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
            fy = Gears.r.nextInt(500) + 1;
            g.fillOval(fx, fy, 100,100);
            repaint();

        }

    }

    g.drawRect(x,y,100,100);
    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.drawString("Roamcraft", nx, ny);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until [no code can be removed while still running into the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, it would help a lot if you explained what you mean by "spazzing".

Comment: Please stop calling `repaint` from inside `paintComponent(...)` method, this is leading to recursive calls, when you only need to paint once. Stop calculating thingies, insde the `paintComponent(...)`. First calculate what needs to be done, and then simply call `repaint`, which will implicitly call `paintComponent(...)`